# Why am I getting Segmentation fault: 11?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to learn c, so I have been trying to figure out why I have segmentation fault for the last 2 hours; On paper it looks like the code should work..

So the purpose of the procedure is to ask the user to enter the size they need in heap, then ask them to enter the numbers, but the numbers must be unique.

**Please excuse me if this is badly indented code, I'm still a beginner**

```
int size ; // The size to allocate
int input ; // the number the user will enter from keyboard
int count  = 0 ; // how many numbers have been added


printf ("Enter the number of integers to process: \n");
scanf ("%d" , &size) ;
int* t;
int* c= (int*)malloc (size* sizeof (int));

if ((t = c))
while (count<size)
{
  printf("Enter value #%d\n" , count+1) ;
  scanf ("%d" , &input) ;

  if (count != 0)
  while (t<= t+count-1)
  {

      if (*t == input)
      {
         printf ("You have entered %d already\n", input);
         printf("Enter value #%d\n" , count+1) ;
         scanf ("%d" , &input) ;
         t = c ;
      }
    else
     t++;
  }

  t = c ;
  c[count] = input ;
  sum += c[count] ;
  count ++ ;
}
```

Comment: Please note that i'm trying to use pointer arithmetic, I am aware that there are easier ways to doing this.

Comment: What is this `if ((t = c))`?

Comment: To assign the pointer c to t, and at the same time check if malloc returned null or not

Comment: Offtopic: For integrals and pointers, `x <= y-1` is equivalent to `x < y` – not for floating point, though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be 
`while (t<= c+count-1)`

instead of
`while (t<= t+count-1)`

The latter condition is always true.